# Largest possible eigenvalue of the covariance matrix of a smooth probability distribution on the sphere is attained for the uniform distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, uniform-distribution, covariance, spectral-radius

Let $\mathcal P$ the set of all probability distributions on the sphere $\Bbb S^n\subset \Bbb R^{n+1}$ that have smooth densities with respect to the Lebesgue surface measure. For all $P\in\mathcal P$ let
$$
   \rho(P)=\max_{\lambda \in \Bbb S^n}\lambda^T Cov(P) \lambda
$$
the largest eigenvalue of the covariance matrix
$$
   Cov(P)=\left(\int_{\Bbb S^n} x_ix_j P(dx)-\int_{\Bbb S^n} x_i P(dx)\int_{\Bbb S^n} x_j P(dx)\right)_{i,j=1,\ldots,n+1}.
$$
It seems intuitively clear to me that if $\mathcal U$ denotes the uniform distribution on $\Bbb S^n$, then we should have
$$
   \sup_{P\in\mathcal P}\rho(P)=\rho(\mathcal U).
$$
I am looking for a reference for this statement.

I thought this might be found in Directional Statistics by Kanti Mardia and Peter Jupp, but so far I've had no luck finding it there.

PS: I am aware that $Cov(\mathcal U)=(n+1)^{-1}\cdot 1_{(n+1)\times(n+1)}$ and hence $\rho(\mathcal U)=(n+1)^{-1}$. That is not part of my question.

Comment: It seems doubtful to me: imagine a distribution on the sphere close to a Dirac one, hence with a very small covariance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim
$$
   \sup_{P\in\mathcal P}\rho(P)=\rho(\mathcal U)
$$
is **false**.

Let $p=(1,0,\ldots,0)\in\Bbb S^n$ and
$$
   P=\frac 12 (\delta_p+\delta_{-p}).
$$
Then
$$
   \int_{\Bbb S^n} x_ix_j P(dx)-\int_{\Bbb S^n} x_i P(dx)\int_{\Bbb S^n} x_j P(dx)= \begin{cases} 1, & i=j=1, \\ 0, & \text{else,}\end{cases}
$$
and hence
$$
   \rho(P)=1.
$$
If $(P_m)_{m\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of smooth approximations of $P$, i.e. $P_m\to P$ for $m\to\infty$ in the sense of weak convergence of probability measures, then (by compactness of $\Bbb S^n$) we have
$$
   Cov(P_m)\to Cov(P),
$$
and therefore
$$
   \rho(P_m)\to\rho(P)=1.
$$
Hence
$$
   \sup_{P\in\mathcal P}\rho(P)\ge 1>\frac{1}{n+1}=\rho(\mathcal U).
$$
(Since $1$ is trivially also an upper bound, we have $\sup_{P\in\mathcal P}\rho(P)=1$.)

Comment: Here is an upshot of the discussion so far: Sup of max eigenvalue $= 1$, sup of min eigenvalue $= (n+1)^{-1}$, inf of max (or min) eigenvalue $= 0$.

Comment: @Levent Thanks a lot for your input. I've just posted another question with the same flavor [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4694991/largest-eigenvalue-of-the-covariance-matrix-of-a-smooth-unimodal-probability-dis).