# Largest eigenvalue of the covariance matrix of a smooth unimodal probability distribution on the sphere?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, uniform-distribution, covariance, spectral-radius

For any probability distribution $P$ on the sphere $\Bbb S^n\subset \Bbb R^{n+1}$ let $\lambda_{max}(P)$ denote the largest eigenvalue of its covariance matrix
$$
   Cov(P)=\left(\int_{\Bbb S^n} x_ix_j P(dx)-\int_{\Bbb S^n} x_i P(dx)\int_{\Bbb S^n} x_j P(dx)\right)_{i,j=1,\ldots,n+1}.
$$

**Question:** Assume that $P$ has a density $p$ with respect to the Lebesgue surface measure and that $p$ is unimodal, i.e. it has exactly one local maximum. Is it true that then
$$
   \lambda_{max}(P)<\lambda_{max}(\mathcal U),
$$
where $\mathcal U$ denotes the uniform distribution on $\Bbb S^n$?

This seems like a relatively obvious question, and I'd expect that either a counter example or a proof is known - and I am looking for a reference. I'd be surprised if the answer to the question was no. Note that in any case [the unimodality assumption cannot be dropped](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4694617/largest-possible-eigenvalue-of-the-covariance-matrix-of-a-smooth-probability-dis).

PS: I am aware that $Cov(\mathcal U)=(n+1)^{-1}\cdot 1_{(n+1)\times(n+1)}$ and hence $\lambda_{max}(\mathcal U)=(n+1)^{-1}$. That is not part of my question.

Answer (score 2):

"Exactly one local maximum" is too weak a condition to imply anything. Indeed, take any reasonable smooth density with finitely many local maxima, draw a  region of very small area encompassing all these maxima and, say, homeomorphic to a ball, and pull the density up there keeping the boundary values, so that there will be only one maximum after that but there would be not much change in the $L^1$ norm (you'll need to renormalize a bit, but it is not an issue either). So, if you have something like what you are interested in in the class of unimodal probability densities, you'll actually have it for all densities, and you have indicated that you know yourself that the latter is false.

Comment: I am having some troubles with this answer. I think the idea is to approximate any density with a unimodal one. Since the claim is false for a general density, it should be false for a unimodal one. However, if you look at the counter-example (in the linked question) that the claim is false for a general density, it is of the form  $\frac{1}{2}(\delta_{p}+\delta_{-p})$ where $p$ is a point and $\delta$ is the Dirac distribution. I am not convinced that the unimodal approximation to this distribution is close to the original one, since the modes, $p,-p$, are far away from each other.

Comment: Moreover, after you approximate $\frac{1}{2}(\delta_{p}+\delta_{-p})$ with a unimodal one as you suggested, I have a suspicion that you indeed get a distribution where the max eigenvalue is bounded by $(n+1)^{-1}$, so you do not obtain a counter example. Indeed, I tried to do this for $n=1$, i.e., circle, case and the unimodal density you obtain with your method is something like a Gaussian on the parameter space $[0,2\pi)$. I think this density has max eigenvalue bounded by $(n+1)^{-1}$.

Comment: @Levent You cannot do it for $n=1$ because you cannot include two faraway points into a small area domain,. Apologies for not mentioning that. My argument works if the dimension of the sphere is 2 or higher.